# How to calculate the betweenness using the random walk algorithm?

Tags: r, social-networking, networkx, igraph

The igraph package calculates the betweenness using shortest path between nodes.
http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/betweenness.html

Now I want to calculate the betweenness using the random walk.

[A measure of betweenness centrality based on random walks, M. E. J. Newman, Social Networks 27, 39-54 (2005).](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0309045.pdf)

I know that NetworkX in python can implement this function. But it turns out the memory error because of the large network I used.

Is there any suggestion about how to calculate betweenness using the random walk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After running for three days and nights, the computer finally obtained the result of betweenness using NetworkX.

The graph I used consists of about six thousand nodes and 5 million edges. The RAM of computer is 16G.

The [solver](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.current_flow_betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.current_flow_betweenness_centrality) is set to “full” (uses most memory), not the default 'lu'.

[This link](https://networkx.lanl.gov/trac/ticket/740) also mentioned the problem of run time using NetworkX to calculate the betweenness based on random walk.